# UICollectionViewCell with UIButton radio button - one radioButton selected at time

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, radio-button, uicollectionviewcell

I have UICollectionView with UIButton as a radio Button in UICollectionViewCell.xib.

I need one radioButton selected at time, if next was pressed, previous should be deselected. I will appreciate help.

```
//Loading radio button when view loads
-(void)setRadioButton{

    if (!self.product.isSelectedCell) {
        [self.radioBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.radioBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button-select"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

//Action for radio button
- (IBAction)radioBtnAction:(UIButton*)sender {

    if([self.radioBtn isSelected]==YES)
    {
      [self.radioBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button-select"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
       else{
//always calls else 
            [self.radioBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have multiple buttons in each cell or each cell contains only one button?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR each cell contains one button

Comment: Show number of items and cell for item methods

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I'm loading a UICollectionViewCell.xib for cell, so there's no datasource methods

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath

        UIButton *radioButton = (UIButton *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:kRadioButtonTag]; // Radio button
        [radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_unselected"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioSelected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [radioButton addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown]; 

if(indexPath == selectedIndexPath)
        [radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioSelected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
else
        [radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_unselected"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 Radio button taped from table cell and get index path of that button
Take on class Lebel NSIndexPath variable and store selected index path.

- (void)radioButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil) {
       selectedIndexPath = indexPath
[tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Hope this will help